# Problem to compare a variable with a .get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, tkinter

I have a problem I don't know how to compare a variable with a `.get()` of a Entry so what is the problem?

I'm a python newbie and I'm French

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

liste = ["A TI TA", "B TA TI TI TI", "C TA TI TA TI", "D TA TI TI", "E TI", "F TI TI TA TI", "G TA TA TI", "H TI TI TI TI", "I TI TI", "J TI TA TA TA", "K TA TI TA", "L TI TA TI TI", "M TA TA", "N TA TI", "O TA TA TA", "P TI TA TA TI", "Q TA TA TI TA", "R TI TA TI", "S TI TI TI", "T TA", "U TI TI TA", "V TI TI TI TA", "W TI TA TA", "X TA TI TI TA", "Y TA TI TA TA", "Z TA TA TI TI"]

class Interface(Frame):
    def __init__(self, fenetre, **kwargs):

    def cliquer():
        lettrer = choice(liste)
        self.lettre["text"] = lettrer

    def verification():
        if saisie.get() == (lettrer):
            showinfo("Saisie correcte", "Saisie correcte")
        else:
            showinfo("Erreur", "ERREUR")

    Frame.__init__(self, fenetre, width=768, height=576, **kwargs)
    self.pack(fill=BOTH)


    self.message2 = Label(self, text="APRENDRE LE CODE MORSE")
    self.message2.pack(side="top")

    self.message = Label(self, text="Cliquez sur générer")
    self.message.pack()

    self.lettre = Label(self, text="")
    self.lettre.pack()

    saisie= StringVar()
    self.champ = Entry(self, textvariable = saisie, bg = "bisque", fg = "maroon")
    self.champ.focus_set()
    self.champ.pack()

    self.bouton_quitter = Button(self, text="Quitter", command=self.quit)
    self.bouton_quitter.pack(side="left")

    self.bouton_cliquer = Button(self, text="Generer", textvariable = "lettrer", command = cliquer)
    self.bouton_cliquer.pack(side="right")

    self.confirmbouton = Button(self, text="Valider", command = verification)
    self.confirmbouton.pack()


fenetre = Tk()
interface = Interface(fenetre)

interface.mainloop()
interface.destroy()
```

My errors when i press "valider" :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\albru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/albru/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/interface.py", line 15, in verification
    if saisie.get() == (lettrer):
NameError: name 'lettrer' is not defined
```

ZeEleveZozo

Comment: That variable is not defined. It has nothing to do with the comparison or the `.get`. also, none of your methods take a self argument....

Answer (score 0):

There is no lettrer in the scope of that function, you need to use self.lettrer instead. So, change "if saisie.get() == (lettrer):" to "if saisie.get() == (self.lettrer):".

Comment: You'll need to flesh out this answer a little bit more. Feel free to copy relevant parts of the code from the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

At this point:

```
if saisie.get() == (lettrer):
            showinfo("Saisie correcte", "Saisie correcte")
```

`lettrer` is not defined. Why? Because `lettrer` is not a global variable. It's an instance variable of `Interface`. In order to indicate that you want to compare `saisie.get()` to the instance variable `lettrer`, you need to prepend `self.` to it like so:

```
if saisie.get() == self.lettrer:  # I removed the redundant parantheses
            showinfo("Saisie correcte", "Saisie correcte")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use oops with tkinter try to make every variable global in the class with the use of `self` (`self.saisie = StringVar()`) specially when you use that variable in a different function.

Also definition a function inside is not a bad approach but it can be better if you define it with `self` outside the class.

One more thing it gives an error if you press 'Generer' button before pressing 'Quitter' button this is because 'lettrer' variable will only define if you press 'Quitter' so either you define it in `__init__` as `self.lettrer = None` or just give a first random choice by `self.lettrer = choice(liste)`. This will prevent you from the error: `AttributeError: 'Interface' object has no attribute 'lettrer'`.

**Here is the updated code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

liste = ["A TI TA", "B TA TI TI TI", "C TA TI TA TI", "D TA TI TI", "E TI", "F TI TI TA TI", "G TA TA TI", "H TI TI TI TI", "I TI TI", "J TI TA TA TA", "K TA TI TA", "L TI TA TI TI", "M TA TA", "N TA TI", "O TA TA TA", "P TI TA TA TI", "Q TA TA TI TA", "R TI TA TI", "S TI TI TI", "T TA", "U TI TI TA", "V TI TI TI TA", "W TI TA TA", "X TA TI TI TA", "Y TA TI TA TA", "Z TA TA TI TI"]

class Interface(Frame):
    def __init__(self, fenetre, **kwargs):

        Frame.__init__(self, fenetre, width=768, height=576, **kwargs)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH)

        self.lettrer = choice(liste)
        self.message2 = Label(self, text="APRENDRE LE CODE MORSE")
        self.message2.pack(side="top")

        self.message = Label(self, text="Cliquez sur générer")
        self.message.pack()

        self.lettre = Label(self, text="")
        self.lettre.pack()

        self.saisie= StringVar()
        self.champ = Entry(self, textvariable = self.saisie, bg = "bisque", fg = "maroon")
        self.champ.focus_set()
        self.champ.pack()

        self.bouton_quitter = Button(self, text="Quitter", command=self.quit)
        self.bouton_quitter.pack(side="left")

        self.bouton_cliquer = Button(self, text="Generer", textvariable = "lettrer", command = self.cliquer)
        self.bouton_cliquer.pack(side="right")

        self.confirmbouton = Button(self, text="Valider", command = self.verification)
        self.confirmbouton.pack()

    def cliquer(self):
        self.lettrer = choice(liste)
        self.lettre["text"] = self.lettrer

    def verification(self):
        if self.saisie.get() == self.lettrer:
            showinfo("Saisie correcte", "Saisie correcte")
        else:
            showinfo("Erreur", "ERREUR")


fenetre = Tk()
interface = Interface(fenetre)

interface.mainloop()
interface.destroy()
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

below my version, if it's not too late ;)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import random


class Main(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent

        self.saisie = tk.StringVar()
        self.letre = tk.StringVar()
        self.liste = ["A TI TA", "B TA TI TI TI", "C TA TI TA TI",
                      "D TA TI TI", "E TI", "F TI TI TA TI", "G TA TA TI",
                      "H TI TI TI TI", "I TI TI", "J TI TA TA TA",
                      "K TA TI TA", "L TI TA TI TI", "M TA TA", "N TA TI",
                      "O TA TA TA", "P TI TA TA TI", "Q TA TA TI TA",
                      "R TI TA TI", "S TI TI TI", "T TA", "U TI TI TA",
                      "V TI TI TI TA", "W TI TA TA", "X TA TI TI TA",
                      "Y TA TI TA TA", "Z TA TA TI TI"]

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        f = ttk.Frame()
        ttk.Label(f, text = "APRENDRE LE CODE MORSE").pack()
        ttk.Label(f, text = "Cliquez sur générer").pack()
        ttk.Label(f, textvariable = self.letre).pack()
        self.champ = tk.Entry(f,
                              textvariable = self.saisie,
                              bg = "bisque",
                              fg = "maroon")
        self.champ.pack()
        self.champ.focus_set()

        w = ttk.Frame()

        ttk.Button(w, text="Generer",command=self.cliquer).pack()
        ttk.Button(w, text="Valider", command=self.verification).pack()
        ttk.Button(w, text="Quitter", command=self.on_close).pack()


        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)


    def cliquer(self,):
        lettrer = random.choice(self.liste)
        self.letre.set(lettrer)

    def verification(self):
        if self.saisie.get():

            if self.saisie.get() == (self.letre.get()):
                msg ="Saisie correcte"
            else:
                msg="Erreur"

            messagebox.showinfo(self.parent.title, msg)
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning(self.parent.title, 'Please fill saisie field')

    def on_close(self):
        self.parent.on_exit()


class App(tk.Tk):
    """Start here"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_exit)

        self.set_style()
        self.set_title() 
        Main(self,)     

    def set_style(self):
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        #('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative')
        self.style.theme_use("clam")

    def set_title(self):
        s = "{0}".format('MORSE')
        self.title(s)

    def on_exit(self):
        """Close all"""
        if messagebox.askokcancel( self.title(), "Do you want to quit?", parent=self):
            self.destroy()               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]